# Печатная версия rtl-сайта

Tags: wordpress, rtl

Почему при загрузке `rtl.css` ему назначается атрибут `media="screen"`, в то время как для других файлов стилей — `media='all'`?

Как в таком случае подготовить печатную версию для `rtl`-сайта?